# How to Add CSS Class to This Ruby Injection?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My problem is that whenever html content is image, I want it to be `class="img-responsive"`. Otherwise big images are looking horrible.
I tried to set class of parent div to `img-responsive` but somehow it doesn't get inherited.

So I'm trying to add this CSS class to following Ruby injection somehow:

`<%= raw(activity.trackable.content_html) %>`

I tried this
`<%= raw(activity.trackable.content_html), :class => "img-responsive" %>` but gives syntax error.

Comment: how's your `activity.trackable.content_html` look like?

Comment: @Emu , In a loop, first iteration evaluates to: `<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fc/Sahelanthropus_tchadensis_-_TM_266-01-060-1.jpg" alt=""/></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

Wrap up the `raw` statement with a div and give a `id` to that div.

```
<div id="image-wrapper">
   <%= raw(activity.trackable.content_html) %>
</div>
```

now, in your `custom.css` file or other asset file add `img-responsive` class elements to a new css, like:

in **custom.css**

```
#image-wrapper p img{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

It'll do the trick whenever it finds an image inside the newly created `div`.

Comment: Thank fckin god it worked. I was about to smash my screen... Thanks a lot. And btw, do you have any idea why CSS class doesn't get inherited from parent?

Comment: @Saibot, css class will inherit from the parent with proper reference.

Comment: Well, can you give an example to a proper reference?